# Can an atom be simulated based on the current theories related to charge?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, atoms

I am not speaking about using computer graphics to visualize a atom, but to actually take 2 balls and charge/neutralize them to simulate an atom.

Comment: How would that work? Subatomic particles aren't like classical balls.

Comment: You don’t “simulate” an atom with graphics. You might “visualize” one but if you did you would likely be visualizing an obsolete and incorrect model (more correct models are boring to “look” at). Detailed computational simulations are done but they don’t make pretty pictures: they make rows and columns of numbers representing thing rather more abstract (and useful) then little balls in motion.

Comment: @dmckee I have made the required changes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An atom is far more complex than 2 charged balls orbiting each other. For a start, you have to take into account quantum effects, which means simulating the wavefunction. One of the reasons that it was necessary to develop quantum theory is because the classical model of the atom being like an orbital system of classical particles would predict that electrons would lose all their energy and fall into the nucleus.

The other thing to consider is that protons and neutrons are not fundamental particles - they are each composed of three quarks, which interact with each other via the strong nuclear force. So, again, the nucleus is more complex than a simple classical 'ball' model could describe.

Comment: So we cannot simulate an atom by any means apart from computer graphics?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow I have to confess that I don't know the extent to which atoms can be simulated (perhaps someone else could speak to that). However, I know that it is much more complex than simulating an orbital system of balls. Tbh, computer graphics is largely irrelevant to the task of conducting simulations of physical phenomena: simulation is about predicting a system numerically; computer graphics is about how to render some type of data on a screen (which could be totally made-up). A physical simulation can be conducted without rendering an image and vice-versa.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow for example, computer games often use 'simplified' physics engines to give a rough approximation of physical phenomena; however, they don't necessarily represent the physics in an accurate or academically rigorous way.

Comment: Has any scientist actually seen a H2O molecule vibrate?

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow If depends what you mean by "see". You can certainly *measure* molecular vibration using X-ray diffraction and/or neutron scattering for example.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow I don't know, but perhaps you could ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Time4Tea Here's it https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511242/has-any-scientist-actually-seen-a-h2o-molecule-vibrate

Answer (score 1):

In order to experimentally simulate an atom using charged balls you need a working classical model of an atom. It is certainly possible to put a negatively charged  ball in orbit around a positively charged one, but this system will not behave as an atom. The system will loose energy as EM waves (because the charge accelerates) and you will not have quantified orbits, as real atoms have.

I can point you to two proposed classical solutions:

1. The free-fall model

Radially Oscillating Electron-the Basis of the Classical Model of the Atom

M. Gryzinski (1965),  Physical Review Letters. 14 (26): 1059–1059.
doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.14.1059

I think the idea behind this model is that once the magnetic moment of the electron is taken into account the electron cannot fall into the nucleus.

2. Stochastic electrodynamics

On the extended Stochastic Electrodynamics Interpretation of Quantum
Mechanics

A. F. Kracklauer 2019 J. Phys.: Conf. Ser. 1251 012027

The idea here is that the electron does radiate but its energy is replenished from its interaction with the zero point field (an EM field that takes the role of the quantum vacuum).

You can find a simulation that uses this idea in a fluid-dynamic context:

Transition Orbits of Walking Droplets
Joshua Parker
https://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1127&context=physsp