# Has any scientist actually seen a $H_2O$ molecule vibrate?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, atoms, vibrations, molecules

Has any scientist **experimentally** confirmed that **H2O molecules** vibrate when heat energy is provided to them?

Maybe by passing X-Rays through them or by some special camera...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has any scientist practically confirmed that H2O molecules vibrate...

Yes, molecular vibration and rotation can be measured using [Raman Spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_spectroscopy).

> when heat energy is provided to them?

And yes, the population in rotationally/vibrationally excited states depends on the temperature of the molecules.

You can see some nice spectra of this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational%E2%80%93vibrational_spectroscopy).

**Side note:** A really beautiful technique ([optical centrifuge](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.3420)) has been developed in recent decades to make molecules spin ridiculously fast (to the point of even breaking them apart), using short laser pulses.

Comment: Is the motion continuous or random?

Comment: Which motion? If you mean the vibration/rotation acquired by molecules through heating them up, the phases are all random, but the amount you have in every rovibrational state should end up being well-described by a Boltzmann distribution.

Comment: Is the motion continuous or random? I mean when we look at a few consecutively taken snap(s)/record(s) for a particular molecule, does the molecule be near its previous position or does it seem as if it teleported from time to time? Please answer my question with reference to some readings which were actually taken.

Comment: If we are talking about a single molecule, and you have it in a particular molecular ro-vibrational state, it will evolve "continuously" according to the laws of quantum mechanics. Check this out: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/CP/C4CP04434G#!divAbstract

Comment: Is there experiment that was actually performed to prove it? Or perhaps prove that the motion of each water molecule is continuous?

Comment: Their experiment was with O2 and D2 molecules (not H2O). Its common to use molecules like this for such experiments as rotational states of linear molecules are easier to control.

Comment: [Image from your reference link](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/Image/Get?imageInfo.ImageType=GA&imageInfo.ImageIdentifier.ManuscriptID=C4CP04434G&imageInfo.ImageIdentifier.Year=2015) Is this how a molecule looks..?

Comment: I mean practically...or is it some sort of visual representation?